# How to save and load in-memory dbplyr database to disk?

Tags: r, database, dplyr, tidyverse, in-memory-database

One can create an in-memory database with the `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
copy_to(con, mtcars)
```

Is there a way to save this DB to a file and reload it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can save data into a local SQLite database in a file.

```
library(DBI)
library(RSQLite)

# create a connection to a local file named mtcars.db located in user's home folder
conn <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "~/mtcars.db")
# write mtcars data into the local SQLite file
dbWriteTable(conn, "mtcars", mtcars, overwrite = T)
# read the data from the database file into another variable
mtcars2 <-  dbReadTable(conn, "mtcars")
```